# Does it make sense to have an init file for firebase?

Tags: firebase

In my Typescript-React-Firebase app, I've created a file with the following content:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';

firebase.initializeApp({ ... });

export default firebase;
```

I'm then importing `firebase` from here in the other files in my project.

Is this correct / necessary? Could I just call initialize once in my top level component and then import `firebase` from `firebase/app` and `firebase/auth`? Is there a disadvantage to my approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach is quite common, as it allows you to centralize the Firebase configuration data and initialization call, while also simply using the Firebase SDK everywhere else.